# Пустые поля в БД

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте, у меня есть форум на javascript+php. Отправка сообщений через get запрос, в urlencode, PHP обрабатывает и пишет в БД сообщения пользователей. Но есть одна проблемма. Пользователь может написать комментарий " " - имхо в скобках пробел, и он добавится в БД, помогите как бороться.
Заранее благодарю.

---

Ребята помогите, теперь люди вводят сообщения Alt+0106 и опять пробелы, как быть?

Comment: Alt+0106 - это, если я не ошибаюсь, просто буква j, чем она вам не понравилась? В любом случае предлагаю вспомнить, что вы - программист, а не водопроводчик, случайно севший за компьютер. И наконец-то прочитать хотя бы документацию про функцию `trim()`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$comment = trim($_GET['comment']);
if ($comment != '') {
    /* Добавляем в БД */
}
```

Comment: А если пробелов будет много?

Comment: Удалит много пробелов

Comment: только проверу лучше с !empty делать

Comment: Можно код?

Comment: Можно вообще if ($comment) {} сделать, пуская строка интерпретируется как false.

Comment: Может быть не пустая строка, а несколько пробелов, что уже не является false

Comment: @Bullet777, снова возвращаемся к `trim()`.

Comment: @Bullet777, функция trim удаляет пробелы с конца и начала строки. Если там будут одни пробелы, то она удалит все, оставив пустую строку.

Comment: а ведь всего лишь документацию почитать... это к слову "а если несколько пробелов" :)

Answer (score 0):

**klopp**, понимаете, дело в том, что эта так называемая комбинация Alt+0106 делает в строке ввода некий пробел, и далее, если отправить без текста, а только с этим пробелом, то он отправляет, не выдавая ни какую ошибку, вот хотелось узнать, как залотать данную ахинею (Можно сказать баг), чтобы всякие юзеры не флудили пользуясь этим пробелом.

Comment: Вам религия запрещает узнать, какой именно "невидимый" символ попадает во ввод при нажатии такой комбинации? А что с ним делать - говорить не буду, раз никто до сих пор не упомянул про функцию `trim()`.

Comment: Хорошо, затронем trim(), как я понял, этот скрипт удаляет ненужные пробелы в начале и конце поля ввода, но как вы упомянули ранее, что это комбинации имеет символ j, тогда вопрос, как trim() его удалит? Если этот пробел имеет некий символ?

Comment: @in1, по *стандартным библиотечным функциям* (к которым относится и `trim()` в PHP) любого языка (в отличие от расширений, нестандартных классов и т.д.) всегда имеется максимально подробная документация. Любой человек, приступая к изучению любого языка, *должен начинать с этой документациии*. Начните и вы с правильного конца, сразу поймёте всю глупость переливания из пустого в порожнее "про пробелы" в течении нескольких часов. И вообще, узнаете много нового и интересного, а не будете гадать и фантазировать на уровне "как я прнял".

Comment: @in1, в trim() можно задать какие символы удалять, почитайте документацию - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, с такой ситуацией никогда не сталкивался. Без urldecode просто ответ: "В ", с ним " ".. Извиняйте за то что нуб.